# Order by not working when insert in temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query, and when I execute it in SQL Server 2012, the `ORDER BY` clause is not working. Please help me in this. Regards.

```
DECLARE @Data table (Id int identity(1,1), SKU varchar(10), QtyRec int,Expiry date,Rec date)
DECLARE @Qty int = 20

INSERT @Data 
VALUES
    ('001A', 5 ,'2017-01-15','2015-11-14'),
    ('001A', 8 ,'2017-01-10','2015-11-14'),
    ('001A', 6 ,'2015-12-15','2015-11-15'),
    ('001A', 25,'2016-01-01','2015-11-16'),
    ('001A', 9 ,'2015-12-20','2015-11-17');

SELECT * 
INTO #temp 
FROM @Data 
ORDER BY Id DESC

SELECT * 
FROM #temp
```

Comment: When i am trying to insert in temp table using order by Id desc  and then select from temp table. Id remain in ascending order

Comment: You can't decide the order the data is stored. You can only decide SELECT order (using the ORDER BY clause.)

Comment: i have scenario like that i have to do in this way

Comment: This is link of actual query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ef204/3. Here i want the selection of Qty. Qty should be selected from SKU who is going to expire first.

Comment: Taking stock that is going to expire first has nothing to do with assuming select from temp. table is in the same order it was inserted into it. You're most likely trying to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: if i make selection order by on Expiry in temp table then i can achieve this what i want

Answer (score 22, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

When you `SELECT` from a table, then the results are *unordered*.  The one exception is when you use an `ORDER BY` in the outer query.  So, include an `ORDER BY` and the results will be in order.

EDIT:

You can eliminate the *work* for the sort by introducing a clustered primary key.

```
create table #temp (
    Id int identity(1,1) primary key clustered, 
    SKU varchar(10),
    QtyRec int,
    Expiry date,
    Rec date
);
```

Then when you do:

```
insert into #temp(SKU, QtyRec, Expiry, Rec)
    select SKU, QtyRec, Expiry, Rec
    from @Data
    order by id;
```

The clustered primary key in `#temp` is guaranteed to be in the order specified by the `order by`.  Then the query:

```
select *
from #temp
order by id;
```

will return the results in order, using the clustered index.  No sort will be needed.

Comment: is there any way that i can achieve this....i want to select in order by ID desc then want to insert in temp table

Comment: @AlinaDilshad: when you insert into the temp tables - you're **again** creating an **unordered set** - you **only** get any kind of order when you do a `SELECT` with an **explicit** `ORDER BY` - no other way.

Comment: Hey Gordon this is link of actual query http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ef204/3. Here i want the selection of Qty. Qty should be selected from SKU who is going to expire first.

Comment: @AlinaDilshad . . . Questions should be asked as questions, not in comments.  Your query in the SQL Fiddle is quite different from the query in this question.  I would suggest you ask another question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am going to initialize another thread.

Comment: Depending on the data size, cost of query, cost threshold set in SQL, you could still end up with a sort due to parallelism.

Comment: @Nic . . . I have never seen an actual sort for an order by on the clustered primary key from a table.  Do you have an example of when this might occur?

Comment: This was needed for STRING_AGG to order the results in a temp table correctly - the ORDER BY doesn't appear to be needed at all since the primary key order is returned regardless

Comment: @Coruscate5 . . . You are missing the point of the answer.  `ORDER BY` is necessary.  Otherwise, the results are not guaranteed to be in any given order.  Period.

Comment: Hit or miss is strangely OK in my scenario (out of 1000 tests, 1000 are ordered - I can handle a few misses, since the detail isn't displayed) - I've yet to find a guaranteed way to get STRING_AGG to order by a detail that is not included in a group

Answer (score 2):

A `SELECT ... INTO` clause will help reach your expected output. I usually use temp tables in this way along with a column with a Row number using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function. It automatically orders the selected rows to the temp table. Or more simply, you can use the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: after SELECT INTO clause, use another SELECT clause to get data

Comment: the ORDER BY clause for temp tables not returned ordered data set by specific column name

Answer (score 2):

You can keep you original logic and add an index after your temp table insertion completes.

```
SELECT
id 
INTO #temp
FROM @Data   

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX c ON #temp(id);
```

The benefit of this solution is that if you were doing a union of two tables prior to the temp table insert, it would allow the data to be sorted like an order by clause. For Example:

```
SELECT
* 
INTO #temp
FROM (
     SELECT
     id
     ,date 
     FROM tableA
     
     union
     SELECT
     id
     ,date 
     FROM tableB) tableAB

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX c ON #temp(id);
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use force option to use forcefully order execution. below is an example.

```sql
create table #temp (
    Id int,
    SKU varchar(10),
    QtyRec int,
    Expiry date,
    Rec date
);

insert into #temp(SKU, QtyRec, Expiry, Rec)
    select SKU, QtyRec, Expiry, Rec
    from @Data
    order by id option (force order)
```

Comment: That isn't what FORCE ORDER does